# Swift Threading Issue with CLLocationManager

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm fairly new to Swift. I'm working on an app that tracks a user's location and also uses MultipeerConnectivity that allows users to chat with one another. It looks like the CLLocationManager is hogging the main thread, so the MultipeerConnectivity chat isn't working properly. I've tried using DispatchQueue.main.async around code blocks in my chat class (example code below), but it's still not working. Is there I way I can thread this so I get location updates and users can chat? Any advice or resources would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
  func join() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.peers.removeAll()
          self.messages.removeAll()
          self.session = MCSession(peer: self.myPeerId, securityIdentity: nil, 
              encryptionPreference: .required)
          self.session?.delegate = self
          guard
          let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first,
          let session = self.session
          else { return }

          let mcBrowserViewController = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: 
              ChatConnectionManager.service, session: session)
          mcBrowserViewController.delegate = self
          window.rootViewController?.present(mcBrowserViewController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Location Manager code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, 
CLLocationManagerDelegate {

private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
@Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus?
@Published var lastLocation: CLLocation?

override init() {
    super.init()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

var statusString: String {
    guard let status = locationStatus else {
        return "unknown"
    }
    
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined: return "notDetermined"
    case .authorizedWhenInUse: return "authorizedWhenInUse"
    case .authorizedAlways: return "authorizedAlways"
    case .restricted: return "restricted"
    case .denied: return "denied"
    default: return "unknown"
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    locationStatus = status
    print(#function, statusString)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }
    lastLocation = location
    print(#function, location)
 }
}
```

I use the location manager in other classes to get the user's last location. For example:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0, longitude: locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)
```

Comment: You'd be better off addressing the problem with Location Manager (if that is the true culprit,  as it shouldn't be causing any performance bottleneck) rather than asking about your workaround.  I'd suggest adding the relevant CL code.

Comment: I've just edited my post to include the location manager class (the class that is using CLLocationManager).